# XML import into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

This is my first time working with XML files. I have been able to read the file into a table. Now I am trying to access the data elements to insert / update into ERP.

I am getting stuck using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql as a guide.

I am only attempting a single retrieval now, trying to keep things simple:
XML:

```
<TranscriptRequest xmlns="urn:org:pesc:message:TranscriptRequest:v1.0.0">
  <TransmissionData>
    <DocumentID xmlns="">88895-20170227180832302-ccd</DocumentID>
    <CreatedDateTime xmlns="">2017-02-27T18:08:32.303-08:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <DocumentTypeCode xmlns="">Request</DocumentTypeCode>
    <TransmissionType xmlns="">Original</TransmissionType>
    <Source xmlns="">
      <Organization>
        <DUNS>626927060</DUNS>
        <OrganizationName>AVOW</OrganizationName>
      </Organization>
    </Source>
    <Destination xmlns="">
      <Organization>
        <OPEID>3419</OPEID>
        <OrganizationName>Charleston Southern University</OrganizationName>
      </Organization>
    </Destination>
    <DocumentProcessCode xmlns="">PRODUCTION</DocumentProcessCode>
  </TransmissionData>
  <Request>
    <CreatedDateTime xmlns="">2017-02-27T00:00:00.000-08:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <Requestor xmlns="">
      <Person>
        <Birth>
          <BirthDate>1985-01-01</BirthDate>
        </Birth>
        <Name>
          <FirstName>Chad</FirstName>
          <LastName>test2</LastName>
        </Name>
        <AlternateName>
          <FirstName>Chad</FirstName>
          <LastName>Walker</LastName>
          <CompositeName>Walker, Chad</CompositeName>
        </AlternateName>
        <Contacts>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine>10260 west st</AddressLine>
            <City>Denver</City>
            <StateProvinceCode>CO</StateProvinceCode>
            <PostalCode>80236</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Phone>
            <CountryPrefixCode>1</CountryPrefixCode>
            <AreaCityCode>303</AreaCityCode>
            <PhoneNumber>8152848</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
          <Email>
            <EmailAddress>cwalker@parchment.com</EmailAddress>
          </Email>
        </Contacts>
      </Person>
    </Requestor>
```

My SQL:

```
USE TMSEPRD

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = [XMLData] FROM [dbo].[CSU_Parchment_XMLwithOpenXML]

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT BirthDate
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ROOT/Request/Requestor/Person/Birth/Birthdate')
WITH 
(
BirthDate varchar(20) '../@BirthDate'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

`Birthdate` remains blank. So far I have tried eliminating the ../ in front of `@Birthdate`, I have tried removing the `@`, I have tried removing `Birthdate` from the path.

Comment: Is your XML complete?  Looks like your missing `</Request></TranscriptRequest>`.

Comment: OpenXml is outdated technology. Consider switching to Xml Data Type Methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods

Comment: You might be getting messed around by namespaces. Take a look at the [WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces).

Comment: I do not know, how this XML is generated, but I'm pretty sure, that the various `xmlns=""` is plain wrong and might lead into troubles if you'd have to pass structure validations...

Answer (score 1):

Using  Xml Data Type Methods

```
DECLARE @XML XML='<TranscriptRequest xmlns="urn:org:pesc:message:TranscriptRequest:v1.0.0">
  <TransmissionData>
    <DocumentID xmlns="">88895-20170227180832302-ccd</DocumentID>
    <CreatedDateTime xmlns="">2017-02-27T18:08:32.303-08:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <DocumentTypeCode xmlns="">Request</DocumentTypeCode>
    <TransmissionType xmlns="">Original</TransmissionType>
    <Source xmlns="">
      <Organization>
        <DUNS>626927060</DUNS>
        <OrganizationName>AVOW</OrganizationName>
      </Organization>
    </Source>
    <Destination xmlns="">
      <Organization>
        <OPEID>3419</OPEID>
        <OrganizationName>Charleston Southern University</OrganizationName>
      </Organization>
    </Destination>
    <DocumentProcessCode xmlns="">PRODUCTION</DocumentProcessCode>
  </TransmissionData>
  <Request>
    <CreatedDateTime xmlns="">2017-02-27T00:00:00.000-08:00</CreatedDateTime>
    <Requestor xmlns="">
      <Person>
        <Birth>
          <BirthDate>1985-01-01</BirthDate>
        </Birth>
        <Name>
          <FirstName>Chad</FirstName>
          <LastName>test2</LastName>
        </Name>
        <AlternateName>
          <FirstName>Chad</FirstName>
          <LastName>Walker</LastName>
          <CompositeName>Walker, Chad</CompositeName>
        </AlternateName>
        <Contacts>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine>10260 west st</AddressLine>
            <City>Denver</City>
            <StateProvinceCode>CO</StateProvinceCode>
            <PostalCode>80236</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Phone>
            <CountryPrefixCode>1</CountryPrefixCode>
            <AreaCityCode>303</AreaCityCode>
            <PhoneNumber>8152848</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
          <Email>
            <EmailAddress>cwalker@parchment.com</EmailAddress>
          </Email>
        </Contacts>
      </Person>
    </Requestor>
  </Request>
</TranscriptRequest>';
```

SQL query:

```
with xmlnamespaces('urn:org:pesc:message:TranscriptRequest:v1.0.0' as ns)
  select t.n.value('BirthDate[1]','date')
  from @XML.nodes('ns:TranscriptRequest/ns:Request/Requestor/Person/Birth') t(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Namespaces

How is this XML generated? Is this under your control? What makes me wonder are  various `xmlns=""` This is defining empty default namespaces over and over... Allthough there is one default NS `xmlns="urn:org:pesc:message:TranscriptRequest:v1.0.0"` in the first line, which seems to be correct.

For this namespace issue there are many solutions:

- Create this without the empty `xmlns` - if this is under your control
- Use `REPLACE` and cut away  `xmlns=""` (be aware of the leading blank!) on string level, before you write this into your xml typed column / variable
- use a wildcard (`*:`) for the namespaces of the first two levels
- Define a namespace alias for the default and let the empty namespaces be the default for the lower levels

### Structure

Your XML seems to be plain `1:1`, only 1 source, 1 destination, one reques. And only 1 person within `<Request>` and again only 1 Name and so on below `<Person>`. There is a `<Contacts>` element, which sounds like `1:n`, but it seems to include only 1 address, 1 phone... Reading plain `1:1` is easy...

I will use a CTE with two calls in `.query()` for an easy approach to solve the namespace issue with a wildcard. This allows to read the rest without namespaces:

**some examples how to read your elements, the rest is up to you...**

```
WITH levels AS
(
    SELECT @xml.query(N'/*:TranscriptRequest/*:TransmissionData/*') AS td
          ,@xml.query(N'/*:TranscriptRequest/*:Request/*') AS rq
)
SELECT --TransmissionData
       td.value(N'(DocumentID/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS DocumentID
      ,td.value(N'(CreatedDateTime/text())[1]',N'datetime') AS td_CreatedDateTime
      --more elemenst...
      ,td.value(N'(Source/Organization/DUNS/text())[1]',N'bigint') AS Source_Organization_DUNS
      --more elements...
      ,td.value(N'(Destination/Organization/OPEID/text())[1]',N'bigint') AS Destination_Organization_OPEID

      --Request
      ,rq.value(N'(CreatedDateTime/text())[1]',N'datetime') AS rq_CreatedDateTime
      --Request-Person
      ,rq.value(N'(Requestor/Person/Name/FirstName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Requestor_FirstName

      --Contacts 
      ,rq.value(N'(Requestor/Person/Contacts/Address/AddressLine/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Requestor_AddressLine
 
FROM levels
```

Comment: At least at subelements `xmlns=""` is quite valid XML ,  https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting , https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#defaulting. Not sure about document element.

Comment: @Serg, yes, it *removes* the outer namespace and lets the inner elements react as if there was no namespace. Thats why you put `ns:` before your first steps in your `XPath`, but you need no namespace for the lower levels. If the given namespace defines such a request, I'm pretty sure, that the whole lot should be covered by the same namespace...

Comment: The xml is not under my control.  I am downloading the data file from a third party.  The XML is suppose to be a 1:1.  Thank you for pointing me in the direction of XML data type methods.

Comment: OK I have the document fully parsed.  My final step is to map these values to various tables/fields in the ERP.  How do I reference these parsed values?  I thought it would be like #temp.DocumentID , etc.

Comment: @Gene Do I understand your *I have the document fully parsed* correctly, when I take, that you have a `SELECT`, which returns all parsed values in a derived table? Try to use `SELECT col1, col2, ... INTO SomeStagingTable FROM ...`. This will write all data into a newly created table. With `SELECT * FROM SomeStagingTable` you can get hands on your data in any way you might need it.

Comment: I apologize for having a mental block on this.  I tried the Select Into approach.  SELECT DocumentID INTO CSU_Parchment_Test produces an invalid column error.  it is the FROM clause that I am tripping on in either the Inset Select or Select Into statements.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand part of my problem.  I was trying to handle a CTE like a derived table.  Since this is a CTE, my understanding is that the data is only available during a single select statement, and as soon as I go onto a Select Into statement, the CTE data is no longer available.  This indicates to me that I need to assign CTE values to variables before I end the CTE select statement.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @Gene not really... A `CTE` behaves like a derived table and is available within the following statement. You can use it as source directly or do a join or other actions. There should be no variable needed. Just try `WITH cte AS (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM sys.objects) SELECT * INTO SomeTable FROM cte;` Now you should find 5 rows of `sys.objects` within a new Table "SomeTable" (you'll have to drop it later...)

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience.  Everything clicked this morning and I was able to deliver the project.

Comment: @Gene Please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!